# Does the time taken to access the object from the aws s3 bucket increase if the number of files keeps increasing in the bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working on a use case in which I have around 10k of files in the AWS s3 bucket and in the future it will be keep increasing. I am using boto3 SDK to access the files. So, in this case time taken to access the file will increase with time or it will be constant (it will not depend on the number of files in the S3 bucket.)

Answer (score 2):

The number of objects has **no impact** on retrieval time for individual objects.